# Event driven microservice - how to init old data?

Tags: events, apache-kafka, microservices

I already have micro-services running and would like to add event(Kafka).

For example, I have a customer service with 10000 customers in the db.  I will be adding an event to the customer service so that whenever a new user is created, it publishes an event in which will be consumed by consumers (like recommendation-service, statistics-service, etc.)

I think the above is clear to me. However, I am not sure how to handle the already-registered customers (10000 customers) as the event will only be triggered when 'NEW' customer registers.

I can 'hack' the service to sync the data manually but what does most people do in this case?

Thank you

I tried to search the topic but couldn't find the ones that I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two strategies that you can follow here. The first is a bulk load of fake "new customer" events into the Kafka topic, as you also suggested. The second approach would be to use the change data capture (CDC) pattern where there is an initial snapshot of all the observed data and then a constant streaming of new data change events, direclty from the database internal log (WAL).

To handle your entire use case, you could use a tool like [Debezium Source Connector](https://debezium.io/) for Kafka Connect platform, but note that you will also need to map its change event into your message format. There are plugins to do that with a configuration-driven approach, but you can also create your custom logic using single message transformations (SMT).